# PopUps for all the Feature layers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, geoext, popup

I am trying to create [GeoExt action button](http://dpaste.de/3Z3Tw/) to fetch the feature info from all the layers. I am still getting the info for my point features but I am getting nothing for the usa:states, that appears in the geoserver by default.

When I looked into the firebug, the html for states does not have anything in it's , http://dpaste.de/NLjzW/. But the species data that I am adding has the contents in the , http://dpaste.de/XR3Ou/. The contents in the body are the result of passing `evt.text` param, which is assigned to the `html: evt.text` in my `addToPopup()` function.

Why is this happening?

**Update:**

I am sorry i forgot to add the [addToPopup()](http://dpaste.de/RMLES/) function before.

I thought that maybe there was no data in the usa:states layer, but it does have the data. If you click on the polygon in this app,

`http://128.196.142.12:8080/geoserver/usa/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=usa:states&styles=&bbox=-124.731,24.956,-66.97,49.372&width=780&height=330&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers`

You can see the data in the polygon.

Comment: Can you add the relevant sections of your code to this post, please? That may help in diagnosis of the problem.

Comment: sorry about that @Kevin, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because yor WMS layers have different URLs and your WMSGetFeatureInfo control doesn't listen any layers event except "pima". Try to configure WMSGetFeatureInfo control the following way:

```
new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
    drillDown: true,
    autoActivate: true,
    infoFormat: "application/vnd.ogc.gml",
    queryVisible: true,
    ...
```

Comment: Ok now I am not getting the pima features. `http://128.196.142.12/geo/test/test_new.html`. The states is working fine. Here is my code, http://dpaste.de/hIbje/

Comment: Oh it seems that if I switch off the USA layer, then I can view the Pima features. Also, once I switch off the USA states layer and then turn it on again, the tool does not collect the states features and the features are empty

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but pls help?

Comment: @Sam007, I've modified my answer, please check it out. I've tested this solution and it works fine - both pima and states layers are queryable.